# How to set where conditions on a relationship field with Laravel?

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-6

I have a Task model with a HasMany relationship to the TaskWork model. This contains entries of work done on the task. I want to get all the tasks where a certain user has logged work and I want to sum the work hours for only that user grouped by task. So far I got the following.

```php
$tasks = $tasks->whereHas('works',
    function ($q) use ($reportedUser, $dateFrom, $dateTo) {
        $q->where('created_by', '=', $reportedUser)
            ->whereBetween('created_at',
                [new Carbon($dateFrom.' 00:00:00'), new Carbon($dateTo.' 23:59:59')]);
    })->get();
```

It gets all the tasks where the user has done work and I can sum the work hours. This works fine until there is only one user who has logged work to the task. But when there are two or more users who have logged work for the same task, then the sum will contain all the works, including other users.

I know this is because the above code translates to a where exists clause. Can I filter out works done by other users without using raw DB queries and joins?

Answer (score 0):

You can try with:

```
$taskworks = Task->whereHas('works', function($q) use($reportedUser, $dateFrom, $dateTo) {
         $q  ->where('created_by', '=', $reportedUser)
             ->whereBetween('created_at', [new Carbon($dateFrom." 00:00:00"), new Carbon($dateTo." 23:59:59")]);
     })->with(['works' => function($q) use($reportedUser, $dateFrom, $dateTo) {
         $q->where('created_by', '=', $reportedUser)
             ->whereBetween('created_at', [new Carbon($dateFrom." 00:00:00"), new Carbon($dateTo." 23:59:59")]]);
     })->get();
```

so it will only choose tasks that has works by user you want in certain period time and then it loads works relationship but also only for this user in certain period of time.

Notice that `whereHas` and `with` has to be used a bit different when using constraints (in first you just pass closure and in second you need to use array).

You should read [Constraining Eager Loads](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent-relationships#constraining-eager-loads) and [Querying Relationship Existence](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence) in documentation